# sum of each column between them in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe like this :

```
dd<-data.frame(col1=c(1,0,1),col2=c(1,1,1),col3=c(1,0,0),col4=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))
```

And i would like to have the sum of each column between them like:

```
col1+col2   col1+col3   col1+col4   col2+col3   col2+col4   col3+col4   
2            2          2          2          2            2
1            1          1          1          1            0
1            1          2          1          2            1
2            1          1          1          1            0
```

I did'nt find any fonctions who does that
Please help me

Comment: The `data.frame` you provided cannot be produced, you have defined different number of rows in the last column than the rest of the columns. When I run your code, R throws an error `Error in data.frame(col1 = c(1, 0, 1), col2 = c(1, 1, 1), col3 = c(1,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 8`. Check the last column, you try to define 8 rows, all other columns have 3.

Answer (score 2):

One base R option might be `combn` + `rowSums`

```
setNames(
  as.data.frame(combn(dd, 2, rowSums)),
  combn(names(dd), 2, paste0, collapse = "+")
)
```

which gives

```
  col1+col2 col1+col3 col1+col4 col2+col3 col2+col4 col3+col4
1         2         2         2         2         2         2
2         1         0         0         1         1         0
3         2         1         2         1         2         1
```

**Data**

```
dd<-data.frame(col1=c(1,0,1),col2=c(1,1,1),col3=c(1,0,0),col4=c(1,0,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And do you know how to do the same but with 3 columns?

Comment: @Aubrée Maybe you can try to replace `2` by `3` in my code

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` possibility could be:

```
map_dfc(.x = combn(names(dd), 2, simplify = FALSE),
        ~ dd %>%
         rowwise() %>%
         transmute(!!paste(.x, collapse = "+") := sum(c_across(all_of(.x)))))

  `col1+col2` `col1+col3` `col1+col4` `col2+col3` `col2+col4` `col3+col4`
        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1           2           2           2           2           2           2
2           1           0           0           1           1           0
3           2           1           2           1           2           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Uglier, and slower than the base R above:

```
do.call("cbind", setNames(Map(function(i){y <- dd[,i] + dd[,-c(1:i)]}, 
                              seq_along(dd)[1:ncol(dd)-1]), names(dd)[1:(ncol(dd)-1)]))
```